# The std::get_temporary_buffer returns raw pointer instead of smart one

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

The [`std::get_temporary_buffer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/get_temporary_buffer) returns a `std::pair` holding a pointer to the beginning of the allocated storage and the number of objects allocated, and the only purpose of its counterpart: [`std::return_temporary_buffer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/return_temporary_buffer) is to deallocate memory previously allocated with `std::get_temporary_buffer`.

Both functions lies on the `<memory>` header which main purpose is to provide tools to enhance memory management (as it name implies) and make memory management more secure.

About the security of the memory management, the `<memory>` header provides also the smart pointers utility which allows to manage the memory in a [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)-like manner and hence making the memory management exception safe.

C++14 also added the [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) helper function, so we can avoid using raw pointers in many cases nowadays.

With all this efforts in reducing the use of raw pointers, realizing that `std::get_temporary_buffer` returns a raw pointer instead of a smart pointer is pretty confusing. Thats why I want to ask:

- Is there any reason for `std::get_temporary_buffer` to return a raw pointer instead of returning a smart one?
- If there's a reason for this "*old fashioned*" way to allocate and deallocate memory manually, which goal it have that cannot be achieved with smart pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the docs for the old SGI STL implementations of `get_temporary_buffer` et al, they say...

> Note: `get_temporary_buffer` and `return_temporary_buffer` are only provided for backward compatibility. If you are writing new code, you should instead use the `temporary_buffer` class.

That effectively acknowledges the desirability of better automated management.  GCC added `temporary_buffer` as an extension (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/libstdc++/api/a00072.html)), but it never made it into the Standard.  Long and short of it is that it's just not that useful, so having a better interface won't have been a priority.  The whole notion of the OS guessing at whether it should give you all the requested memory or some smaller amount flies in the face of the optimistic memory allocation strategies used by most modern Operating Systems, and once you get multiple calls requesting more than the easily available memory, being too generous with the first leaves the others a bit starved: just not a very practical notion.

If you care, you could submit a proposal for a later C++ Standard....

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer is that `std::get_temporary_buffer` was created before smart pointers were standardized, and changing the return value of `std::get_temporary_buffer` in C++11 would have broken code that depended on it, which is absolutely unacceptable for the C++ standard library.

Now, why haven't they standardized a new smart pointer equivalent?
Well, maybe no one was interested in having one. Personally, I find it weird to have one smart pointer own many objects. If you need a smart array, use `std::vector`.